# AppBarLayout.setExpanded(boolean, true) weird animation in support library 23.1.1

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

In my app I expand or contract the `AppBarLayout` on a specific event using `setExpanded(boolean, true)`.

I've got a good result, with a snappy and fluid animation using `com.android.support:design:23.1.0`, then I updated to `23.1.1` and the animation got very slow and not snappy at all.

In the source code of `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`, I located the problem in `animateOffsetTo` (under `public static class Behavior extends HeaderBehavior<AppBarLayout>`), that in the version 23.1.0 was like this:

```
private void animateOffsetTo(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
    final AppBarLayout child, int offset) {
   if (mAnimator == null) {
       mAnimator = ViewUtils.createAnimator();
       mAnimator.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.DECELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);
       mAnimator.setUpdateListener(new ValueAnimatorCompat.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

           @Override
           public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimatorCompat animator) {
               setHeaderTopBottomOffset(coordinatorLayout, child,
                    animator.getAnimatedIntValue());
           }
       });
   } else {
       mAnimator.cancel();
   }
   mAnimator.setIntValues(getTopBottomOffsetForScrollingSibling(), offset);
   mAnimator.start();
}
```

And in the version 23.1.1 is like this:

```
private void animateOffsetTo(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
    final AppBarLayout child, final int offset) {
   final int currentOffset = getTopBottomOffsetForScrollingSibling();
   if (currentOffset == offset) {
       if (mAnimator != null && mAnimator.isRunning()) {
           mAnimator.cancel();
       }
       return;
   }
   if (mAnimator == null) {
       mAnimator = ViewUtils.createAnimator();
       mAnimator.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.DECELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);
       mAnimator.setUpdateListener(new ValueAnimatorCompat.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
           @Override
           public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimatorCompat animator) {
            setHeaderTopBottomOffset(coordinatorLayout, child,
                    animator.getAnimatedIntValue());
           }
       });
   } else {
       mAnimator.cancel();
   }
   // Set the duration based on the amount of dips we're travelling in
   final float distanceDp = Math.abs(currentOffset - offset) /
        coordinatorLayout.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
   mAnimator.setDuration(Math.round(distanceDp * 1000 / ANIMATE_OFFSET_DIPS_PER_SECOND));
   mAnimator.setIntValues(currentOffset, offset);
   mAnimator.start();
}
```

How can I change the expand/contract animation and make is faster?

Comment: Change setDuration???...

Comment: Are you sure this is the exactly problem your are pointing out???

Comment: @MicheleLacorte: How? That's the code of com.android.support:design

Comment: @Nifhel mAnimator.setDuration(value) change value to 100 or what you want

Comment: are you running the code on the emulator or phone?

Comment: @lifeevader On a phone (Nexus 4, 5.1.1)

Comment: it seems its a Lollipop related bug, am running on 4.2 and its not giving me any issues, how do you plan on animating your AppBar? could u give a sample like of how you want the animation to be like maybe we could find alternatives

Comment: @lifeevader: it is hard to describe, is a "close" animation, like it was on v23.1.0 was perfect. It would be great if it would be possible to set mAnimator.setDuration, but since it is private inside the library is not possible.... :-/

Comment: do you mean the expand and contract animation like the one here https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout on gif 2?

Comment: The is right :) But using setExpanded(boolean, true) the animation is automatic, and not dragged by the user.

Comment: What about updating appcompat to 23.1.1?

Comment: Any luck on that? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @Gilson No, I gave up and I changed my layout to work around that :(

Comment: This issue is reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202897) and is scheduled to be fixed in a future release of the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The issue was reported and fixed](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202897)

Answer (score 1):

Just update library to 25.3.1 version.