# AppBarLayout setExpanded speed is slow

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-support-design

Im using a CollapsingToolbarLayout inside the AppBarLayout, the user can expand it or collapse it by using the `setExpanded(boolean)` method from AppBarLayout.

**The problem is the animation is slow and not smooth.**

I have being searching and it seems there is a problem with the support design library (please read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892376/appbarlayout-setexpandedboolean-true-weird-animation-in-support-library-23-1)). But I cant downgrade my support design library cause Im using `BottomSheetBehavior`and I get this errors:

```
Error:(88) No resource identifier found for attribute 'behavior_hideable' in package...
Error:(88) No resource identifier found for attribute 'behavior_peekHeight' in package...
```

Any suggestion to increase the setExpand speed?

Answer (score 0):

use `appBarLayout.setExpanded(true,true);` instead of `setExpanded(boolean)`and the expantion will be animated